# Python -matplotlib.pyplot : draw a pulse train

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having Voltage and admittance data.[image]

```
time_voltage = {1000 :760 , 3000 : 660, 4000 : 580, 6000 : 510,
             7500 : 460,9000 : 430,12000 : 410,13500 : 380}
```

## calculated ==> current / voltage

```
_time_admittance = {1000 :0.636842105 , 3000 : 0.660606061, 4000 : 0.586206897, 6000 : 0.596078431,7500 : 0.267391304,9000 : 0.262790698 ,12000 : 0.248780488,13500 :   0.25}
```

using above data , I need to plot a pulse train like below. But I'm not sure where to start. Can you point me to the right direction

```
sig = np.arange(15000)
sig.fill(0)
for time_at,voltage in time_voltage.items():
        sig[time_at] = voltage
        admittance = voltage - _time_admittance[time_at]
        sig[time_at + 100] = admittance

sig1 = np.arange(15000)
sig1.fill(0)

for time_at,Admittance in _time_admittance.items():
        for index in xrange(100):
            sig1[time_at] = voltage
            sig1[time_at + index] = Admittance


plt.grid = True 
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('black')
ax.grid(True ,color= 'w')
plt.plot(sig)
plt.plot(sig1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add more information, I'm not certain what you need here. Anyways, I would construct a time array  and a corresponding voltage array - or am I completely missing the point ?

Comment: So - you want to create a plot where, at each time point (1000ms, 3000ms,...,13500ms) there is a 100ms long pulse where Y is at the corresponding voltage and zero for the rest? As Svend mentions - you need to construct an array to pass to matplotlib. This would be fairly simple - what have you tried so far?

Comment: SIHA, You are right. Updated the code. I'm not sure how to connect voltage and admittance.

Comment: admittance is the inverse of impedance. Impedance is connected to voltage. as long as you don't understand the math/physics behind your numbers, it will be terribly hard for you to write the code...

Comment: Right now calculating admittance =  current/ Voltage.. is it wrong...? Can you give me additional info..